# Cloud Foundry : Eureka Server as user provided service and add services

Tags: cloud-foundry

The cloud foundry in our organization does not have Spring Cloud services installed. I have created a Eureka Server and deployed it in the Cloud foundry and able to see the Eureka home page

I have created a user provide service and bound the application using the steps provided here (https://github.com/making/cf-eureka-server)!

I have given the following dependencies since there is no Spring CLoud

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-starter-service-registry</artifactId>
         <version>1.5.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

and

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

However I get the following error in the CF logs

```
2017-11-13T14:39:05.238+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
2017-11-13T14:39:05.238+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ... 30 common frames omitted
2017-11-13T14:39:05.238+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2017-Nov-13 09:09:05.237 WARN [DiscoveryClient-HeartbeatExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient - Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2017-11-13T14:39:05.238+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2017-Nov-13 09:09:05.237 WARN [DiscoveryClient-CacheRefreshExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient - Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2017-11-13T14:39:05.238+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2017-Nov-13 09:09:05.237 ERROR [DiscoveryClient-HeartbeatExecutor-0] c.n.d.DiscoveryClient - DiscoveryClient_C2M-LAUNCH-SERVICE/app-launch-service.apps.np.sdppcf.com:d2c76a2f-f2c4-45f9-7e3b-f807 - was unable to send heartbeat!
2017-11-13T14:39:05.238+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
```

The application is Spring boot application and I have enabled Discovery using @EnableDiscoveryClient. Due to this error I cannot see the services in Eureka.

Is it possible to create a Eureka service without Spring Cloud Services installed in Cloud foundry and use feign Clients etc ? Any direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `spring-cloud-services-starter-*` client libraries were developed to match the way that Spring Cloud Services deploys and secures Spring Cloud applications like Eureka. These Spring Cloud Services libraries aren't likely to work with a Eureka service you write yourself unless you implement the same security and other configuration that SCS does.

Instead of using `io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-starter-service-registry`, you should use `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka` and configure Eureka using properties in `application.properties` or `application.yml`. You can set the appropriate properties to values parsed from the user-provided service instance as shown in [making's example from the Github repo](https://github.com/making/cf-eureka-server#bind-eureka-service-to-an-application):

`eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=${vcap.services.eureka-service.credentials.uri:http://localhost:8761}/eureka/`

Comment: I  was able to register with the Eureka server after giving the eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone with the direct URL.It is a temporary fix till the admin comes up with the Spring cloud services in PCF.

Comment: I'm using the same response as a guidance for the same problem but it seems like that my microservice can't register itself with eureka instance. :/ Any suggestion?

Comment: @Habchi You'll need to provide more information than "can't register itself with eureka". You should create a new StackOverflow entry with the details like any information in eureka app or client app logs.